# WPF binding a background color initializes but not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using observable collection and dataTemplates to create generic panels, I have encountered an issue when my buttons colors (setted programaticly) do initializes, but once changed while running the color stays still.

Here is my Xaml code for the button:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Background="{Binding Path=motionColor}" Command="{Binding Path=MotionPress}" Content="Motion" Height="51" Width="104" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
```

That's my DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GenericPanelTemplate"  DataType="local:GenericPanel">
```

And here's the relevant backend code in GenericPanel.cs:

motionColor:

```
public Brush motionColor { get; set; }
```

The function eventually the button execute (tested and running):

```
public void MotionButton_Click()
        {
                motionColor = setColor((byte)Value.ON);
        }
    private Brush setColor(byte value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case (byte)Value.OFF:
                return Brushes.Red;
            case (byte)Value.ON:
                return Brushes.Green;
            case (byte)Value.PROGRESS:
                return Brushes.Yellow;
            default:
                return Brushes.Gray;
        }
    }
```

On start, the motionColor sets to be red, and the button does appear red, but when the value changed to Brushes.Green here it doesnt work anymore (debugging proves that the value changes correctly).

**How do I make the button to check it's binded value and update the Background attribute?**

If more code is needed please ask, I think these functions and Xaml lines are the only relevant ones.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your `GenericPanel` must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface or `motionColor` must be a [dependecy property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx). Otherwise your binding will never know that something has changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` ([MSDN link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on the class containing the property, and notify the changes to your property.

Something like:

```
public GenericPanel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private Brush _motionColor;
  public Brush motionColor { 
    get { return _motionColor; }; 
    set { 
      _motionColor = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged(); 
    }
  }

  /* ... the rest of your class ... */

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)  
  {        
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

This all can be done automatically using [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody/) (specifically [the PropertyChanged add-in](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)) but if you only require it for this specific property, using Fody might be overkill

## Update

Since the OP, as per the comments, seems to be using older versions of .NET and C#, here's the "more compatible" version:

```
public GenericPanel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private Brush _motionColor;
  public Brush motionColor { 
    get { return _motionColor; }; 
    set { 
      _motionColor = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged("motionColor"); 
    }
  }

  /* ... the rest of your class ... */

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)  
  {
    var handle = PropertyChanged;
    if(handle != null) 
      handle(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi what do you mean by [CallerMemberName]?

Comment: `[CallerMemberName]` is an attribute for a parameter that sets the caller member name on that parameter if it has a default value and no value is passed in. So in this case, it'll receive a string with `"motionColor"` as its content (since I'm not passing anything to `OnPropertyChanged()`). More info on [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Using it like that won't compile, I get "Error 2 The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\dp27317\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GenericSoundMotion\GenericSoundMotion\GenericPanel.cs 310 43 GenericSoundMotion"

Comment: You need to add `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;` on top of your file

Comment: If you are under .NET 4.5, just remove `[CallerMemberName]`, and pass the parameter on the property setter: `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(motionColor));`  instead of `OnPropertyChanged();`. `CallerMemberName` is an addition to .NET 4.5 and won't work on earlier versions (well, you can actually make it work if using C# 5.0 or over, but that's outside the scope of this question)

Comment: PropertyChanged?.Invoke(propertyName); is also problematic, it gives these 3 errors:

Invoke does not take 1 arguments, and I think there is a problem with the '?' sign, it gives "invalid expression term'.'

Comment: Yes, that's C# 6 and needs Visual Studio 2015. I'll edit and add an answer for previous versions

Comment: Thanks a lot sorry for the troubles.

Comment: There you go, the updated version should work on previous versions of both .NET and C#

Comment: I updated again, made a mistake on the event invocation (that's for writing off my head ;-) ). It should work now

Comment: It still says the same about the handle function as it did for the invoke, "Delegate PropertyChangedEventHandler' does not take 1 argument, any idea what else should I add?

Comment: The code runs, and motionColor do change to green color but the button still stays red :/

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the property on the bound instance, and not in some other?

Comment: Yep for the last hours I tried to work on it, tried to change the binding to _motionColor as well but none seems to work, the color of the button stays red

Comment: How are you using your `DataTemplate`? With a `ContentControl` or something? If so, are you sure your binding is correct?

Comment: <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Background="{Binding Path=motionColor}" Command="{Binding Path=MotionPress}" Content="Motion" Height="51" Width="104" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>

This is how I bind it, and for starters it does color the background in Red

Comment: Yep, but it could be binding to some other instance of your `GenericPanel`. Where are you using your `DataTemplate`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100044/discussion-between-guy-ben-moshe-and-jcl).